# Copia de archivo dentro de rutas en txt - VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Tengo este código que lee rutas desde un txt, y requiero copiar los archivos con extensión (jpg, pdf, html).

Al momento de ejecutar me sale el error de **acceso denegado**. Ya cambié los permisos de las carpetas y me sigue arrojando el mismo error

Este es el código:

```
Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    filelocation = "U:\Users\alpnheg\Documents\vbcopia\rutas.txt" 'locación del txt

    If myFSO.FileExists(filelocation) Then 'mira si existe el archivo

    Set logfile = myFSO.OpenTextFile(filelocation, 1) 'lee las rutas

    Do While Not logfile.AtEndOfStream 'inicia loop

    strcontents = ""
    strcontents = logfile.ReadLine 

    If Not strcontents = "" then 

            'ARREGLAR ESTA FUNCIÓN
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
            fso.copyfile (filelocation),"U:\Users\alpnheg\Documents\AAAAA",true


    End if      

Loop

logfile.Close 'closes the file
```

Comment: Por favor revisa si tienes permisos de lectura y escritura en la carpeta a la que accedes con este código.

Comment: Intenta realizar una prueba de copia manualmente entre los directorios y chequea que no tenga problema de permisos en el destino.

Comment: Hola! ya lo revisé y cambié los permisos, pero no cambió nada

Comment: @NicoleH.¿el archivo en esta ubicación: `U:\Users\alpnheg\Documents\vbcopia\rutas.txt` existe?, ¿la ruta destino _(donde se va a generar la copia del archivo)_ también existe?

Comment: Hola! si, todo existe

Comment: No entiendo un par de lineas, donde cierras el If del FileExists?, Si tienes un objeto manejador de archivos definido (`myFSO`) porque defines 2 mas abajo?, y la linea `fso.copyfile` no deberia ser `myFSO.copyfile "[CarpetaOrigen]\*.jpg", strcontents,True` ? (y una identica para `*.pdf` y `*.html`)